# If $f$ vanishes at all its points of continuity, then $\|f\| = 0.$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

> Denote by $\mathcal R$ the set of all Riemann integrable functions on $[0,2\pi]$ with norm given by $$ \|f\| = \bigg( \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)|^2dx\bigg)^{1/2}$$
>
> If $f\in \mathcal R$ vanishes at all its points of continuity, then $\|f\| = 0$.

This exercise appeard on a book on Fourier analysis. The unique idea that I had was to use parseval identity: $\|f\|^2 = \sum |c_n|^2$ and then using the identity $f(x)= \sum c_n e^{inx}$ to prove that all Fourier coeffcients must be zero. But this is not possible with  $f$ only being continuous at $x$. We must know more about its derivative.

Any help?

Comment: It doesn't *exactly* prove the desired result without getting into Lebesgue integration, but you might still look up the proof of the Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability, which is along these same lines. You should be able to tweak that proof to get this result without having to actually define Lebesgue integration and prove the relationship between Lebesgue and Riemann integration.

Comment: Do you know Lebesgue integration already?

Comment: Riemann-Lebesque Theorem is all that is needed for the results. I suppose we don't need to go to the exact technical details of measure theory to understand that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Lebesgue's classic theorem: A bounded function is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ iff it is continuous at almost every point of $[a,b]$. In fact, this theorem of Lebesgue is where he came up with the idea of measuring more general sets, and integrating more general functions.

In your case, if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and it vanishes at all points of continuity, then $f$ is zero almost everywhere. So you can choose Riemann sums that are all $0$ that converge to the integral, which gives you $0$ for $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$. The same is also true of $\int_a^b f(t)^2dt$.

Answer (score 4):

What if $f(x) = \left. \begin{cases} \sin x & \text{if $x$ is irrational,} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \right\} \text{?}$

Then $f$ is continuous only at $x\in\{0,\pi,2\pi\},$ and it vanishes there. And $\|f\|^2 = 1/2.$

**PS:** The question initially said "integrable" and later got expanded to "Riemann-integrable". If it's Riemann integrable, then the function above will not serve, since that is not Riemann-integrable.

Comment: This $f$ is not in $\mathcal{R}$. (Maybe that wasn't in the question before, I haven't checked the edit history.)

Comment: OP has clarified that the function is Riemann integrable rather than Lebesgue integrable. This answer is no longer valid.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry for not stating that before. As soon as i saw your answer i modified the hyphothesis.